# Are varieties of two equal ideals equal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am new to the field of algebraic geometry and have a question about polynomial ideals.

Assume we have polynomial ideals $I_1,~I_2$ such that $I_1=I_2$ generated by some polynomial systems $F_1, ~F_2$ over $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Are varieties $V(I_1)$ and $V(I_2)$ equal?

My answer is yes but I am not confident in my explanation, so I was looking for some help.

If varieties are not equal, then assume there exists a polynomial $f\in I_1$ whose zeros belong to $V(I_1)$ but not $V(I_2)$ but, since the ideals are equal, $f\in I_2$, so $V(I_2)$ must contain zeros of $f$ by definition.

Is this explanation incorrect/insufficient?

Comment: Well, writing $V(I)$ more or less implies that $V$ is a function of $I$, does it not?

Comment: You are overthinking this. If the sets are equal, the varieties are equal. The variety of an ideal is not affected by which generators you choose.

Comment: @Gae. S. , I think it does.